# How to stop previous dom element animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to use animation using jquery. When i mouseover the element, it increases the height and when mouseout, returns to original height.

The Problem is when i mouseover from one element to another element, the previous element's animation is still performing. how to stop the animation of the previous element?

Fiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/EVZVQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.stop()`: http://api.jquery.com/stop

```
$('.div_1').mouseover(function(){

    $(this).stop().animate({'height':'200px'},2000);
}).mouseout(function(){

    $(this).stop().animate({'height':'100px'},2000);
});
```

Notice you can chain the event binding functions instead of selecting `.div_1` twice in a row.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EVZVQ/1/

> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation
>   (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being
>   hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now
>   still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height.
>   Callback functions are not called.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/stop*

### Update

You can stop all the divs at once like this (but I'm not sure this is the effect you're looking for):

```
var $divs = $('.div_1');
$divs.mouseover(function(){

    $divs.stop().filter(this).animate({'height':'200px'},250);
}).mouseout(function(){

    $divs.stop().filter(this).animate({'height':'100px'},250);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EVZVQ/2/

Comment: yeah...but how can i use stop to stop the previous element's animation..i am using $(this) to current element animation.

Answer (score 0):

This works better.

```
$('.div_1').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).animate({'height':'200px'},200);
});

$('.div_1').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).animate({'height':'100px'},200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/diode/EVZVQ/7/